# How to use Windows 7 API like Aero Glass, Jump List, etc

Tags: c#, wpf, aero, windows-7

How can I take advantage of the Windows 7 features like Aero Glass, Jump Lists, ect. And minor changes like the icon on the jump list, the color of the jump list. Any good articles?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the Windows API Code Pack:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

> Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft®
>   .NET Framework provides a source code
>   library that can be used to access
>   some features of Windows 7 and Windows
>   Vista from managed code. These Windows
>   features are not available to
>   developers today in the .NET
>   Framework.
>
> The individual features supported in
>   this version (v1.0.1) of the library
>   are:
>
> - Windows 7 Taskbar
>     o Jump Lists, Icon Overlay, Progress Bar, Tabbed Thumbnails, and
>     Thumbnail Toolbars
>
>   - Windows Shell
>         o Windows 7 Libraries
>         o Windows Shell Search API support
>         o Explorer Browser Control
>         o A hierarchy of Shell Namespace entities
>         o Windows Shell property system
>         o Drag and Drop for Shell Objects
>         o Windows Vista and Windows 7 Common File Dialogs, including
>       custom controls
>         o Known Folders and non-file system containers
>   - DirectX
>         o Direct3D 11.0, Direct3D 10.1/10.0, DXGI 1.0/1.1,
>       Direct2D 1.0, DirectWrite, Windows Imaging Component (WIC) APIs
>   - Windows Vista and Windows 7 Task Dialogs
>   - Sensor Platform APIs
>   - Extended Linguistic Services APIs
>   - Power Management APIs
>   - Application Restart and Recovery APIs
>   - Network List Manager APIs
>   - Command Link control and System defined Shell icons

Comment: @Zyphrax (repeat of comment made on another thread here on SO) : As you say, some functionality exposed by the W7 API Code Pack is Vista compatible. I can say with certainty that the TaskBarManager functionality is not usable in Vista : based on Visual Studio 2010 beta 2, where I was able to successfully compile a CodeProject example [1] that referenced the W7 API, but was not able to run the project because : "TaskbarManager.IsPlatformSupported" always returns false. [1] codeproject.com/KB/statusbar/Clipz.aspx

Comment: The API Code pack is a set of managed classes for unmanaged Windows API calls. It makes sense that it heavily relies on the user's OS (and supported API calls). The TaskBarManager can't be used on Vista, because the new TaskBar was simply not implemented in Windows Vista.

Comment: So do I just import the right project into my solution or what? I thought it would be like an assembly.

Comment: You can copy a part of the code and integrate it into your project. Or simply compile the desired project(s) and reference those DLLs from your project.